# How to change mouse scrolling speed in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scroll-wheel

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

How to change mouse scrolling speed in Ubuntu?

I went to mouse settings and I found a mouse speed option, [but nothing for the mouse wheel scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCgiD.png).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a long standing issue in Ubuntu and other Linux distributions. You can increase the amount of steps per scroll using `imwheel`.

In some cases you'll still want to use single step scrolling. You can configure `imwheel` to use single steps when a key such as `Alt` is held down.

https://fostips.com/mouse-wheel-touchpad-scroll-speed-ubuntu/

You will need to switch from Wayland to Xorg to make this work. Hopefully a better solution will be developed some day.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** `imwheel` is the easiest and possibly the only one that will work for you. Here's a quick & simple guide https://askubuntu.com/a/1441416/1654422

Be aware if you are using a laptop and lets say you "undock" and want to use the touchpad for a while, you will have to `pkill imwheel` otherwise scrolling will get jumpy, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510523/imwheel-creates-jittery-scroll-when-using-touch-pad)

Why does that happen? Believe it or not, changing the scroll speed is not supported (at least not out of the box) by neither `gnome` or `libinput`. This has been [reported](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/185) to `libinput` maintainers but they believe people are barking at the wrong tree and this should be fixed [somewhere else](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/379).

There's also [this work-around](https://askubuntu.com/a/1228205/1654422) but it didn't work for me, but some had success.

Comment: TL;CF. What exactly is the `somewhere else` they think is responsible for this?